# Передача между проектами модели в формате JSON, ModelBinder

Tags: asp.net-web-api

Если набрать в браузере ссылку /APIA/GetA/a/a/a/a то данные (modela2) в json отображаются.

```
{
  "id11": "a",
  "id22": "a",      
}
```

Первым проектом пытаюсь передать модель modela во второй проект и получить modela2.

modela передаётся во второй проект.

Первый проект назад modela2 не может получить.

На этой строке не возвращает данные

```
var response = client.PostAsJsonAsync(APP_PATH + "/APIA/GetA", modela).Result;
return response.StatusCode.ToString();
```

> readm2
>
> NotFound

Проект1:

```
string readm2 = GetModelA2(token);
Console.WriteLine("readm2");
Console.WriteLine(readm2);


static string GetModelA2(string token)
        {
            using (var client = CreateClient(token))
            {
                //
                var modela = new ModelA { };
                ...

                var response = client.PostAsJsonAsync(APP_PATH + "/APIA/GetA", modela).Result;
            return response.StatusCode.ToString();
        }
    }
```

Проект2:

```
[RoutePrefix("APIA")]
    public class APIAController : ApiController
    ...
    [Route("GetA/{id1}/{id2}/{id3}/{id4}")]

        public ModelA2 GetA([ModelBinder]ModelA modela)
        {
            ...
            var modela2 = new ModelA2 { };
            ...

            return modela2;
        }
        //




public class ModelA
    {
        public string id1 { get; set; }
        public string id2 { get; set; }
        public string id3 { get; set; }
        public string id4 { get; set; }     
    }

public class ModelA2
    {
        public string id11 { get; set; }
        public string id22 { get; set; }        
    }
```

**Обновлено**

Добавляю это

```
if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    // Parse the response body.
                    var p = response.Content.ReadAsAsync<ModelA2>().Result;
                    //Console.WriteLine("{0}", p.Name);
                    return p.ToString();
                }
```

if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {

> показывает false

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ошибка исправлена. Примерно так:

2

[HttpPost]

[Route("PostA/{id}/{name}")]

public Game2 PostA([ModelBinder]Game game)

1

var response = client.PostAsJsonAsync(APP_PATH + "/APITest/PostA/i/i", game).Result;